# Ember Data Push vs Update

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I received normalized data from the server I often need to get it in the store.  Ember Data has the semantic "push" for that:

```
var thing=normalizedThing
controller.store.push("thing",normalizedThing)
```

If I need to update an existing record I can use update:

```
var updatedThing=normalizedUpdatedThing
controller.store.push("thing",normalizedUpdatedThing)
```

However, I have found that update works even if the record is not loaded in the store yet; ie it will act like push in that case.  However, push will not act like update if the record already exists.  In fact it will throw an error.  So my question is, what is the purpose of push?  Can I safely always call update when wishing to add/update the store with normalized data?  Or should I do the following?

```
var thing=normalizedThing
if(controller.store.getById("thing",normalizedThing.get("id")){
  controller.store.update("thing",normalizedThing)
}else{
  controller.store.push("thing",normalizedThing)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `push` is to load complete records into the store, while `update` is meant to push partial records. So `push` is useful if you want to completely replace a record, possibly removing attributes. So let's say you have the following record in your store:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "status": "Going to the movies today!"
}
```

Now you also have the following JSON you want to load into the store:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob"
}
```

If you use `push`, you'll end us with a user with no status. If you use `update`, the user will have the same status as before. Which one of those you want depends on your use case, but having both `push` and `update` gives you the option for either one.

For me, the point of `push` is to completely replace a record with having to worry about the potential merge conflicts caused by `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/-private/system/store.js#L1680

```
push => 
_pushInternalModel => 
_load => 
_internalModelForId [This find or creates a model] => 
internal-model#setupData

  setupData: function(data) {
    var changedKeys = this._changedKeys(data.attributes);
    merge(this._data, data.attributes);
    this.pushedData();
    if (this.record) {
      this.record._notifyProperties(changedKeys);
    }
    this.didInitalizeData();
  },
```

So it doesn't look like push overwrite any existing data. And seeing how there's no longer an update, I guess they were the same and has been merged. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push